# How to automatically start an sh with current user in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I'm using Ubuntu 14 client as a Jenkins slave and I'm using java to connect to the master node.  So I put those `java -jar slave.jar` stuff into an sh file, and want it to be launched automatically after the system starts.  However, if I put it into `/etc/init.d`, and use `update-rc.d`, I lost necessary environment variables.

I also tried to put the script to `Startup Applications Preferences`, but I don't have those required environment variables either, for example, I don't have `CLASSPATH`, and the `DISPLAY` is :0.  This is so different from the context when I launch the sh manually.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: not working... I copied my scripts to ~/.config/upstart, but it does not get executed....

Comment: Ah, after I added it to `start application preference`, it works.  However, my environment is still not ready...  I don't know why, they are using root to run the scripts?  My observation is if I login my ubuntu, and launch it manually, I get all the correct environment.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Why not either use JNLP or let the Jenkins master SSH into the slave to connect the slave, see [Distributed builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Differentwaysofstartingslaveagents)